# Issue establishing a working AP with Airbase-ngand DNSmasq

Tags: aircrack-ng, dnsmasq

I’m able to run airbase-ng, set DNSmasq with a customized config file that includes dhcp options 3, and 6, with the actual router IP address of the network that has internet, and added public DNS severs addresses. I have activated IP forwarding, do ifconfig at0 up etc, and established the following iptables rules:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -j ACCEPT -i at0
iptables -t nat -POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Then I run dnsmasq and all looks OK. But when I try to connect to the AP, my phone, for instance, takes some time to do it and, when it finally does it and I try to reach any website, it gets stuck and nothing happens. Well, something actually happens: my internet gets broken! And it gets fixed only when I turn off DNSmasq and Airbase...

I really don’t know what to do and would appreciate any ideas as to what is causing these issues and how could I fix it. Thanks in advance!

PS when I start airbase, I use different channel...